# Full Factorial Designs and Honest Tukey

Tags: anova, post-hoc, tukey-hsd-test

I am trying to analyze the data of a 2x2x2x2 full factorial design experiment.  (It wasn't my idea.)

Mercifully, we have plenty of data per run, each run has the same amount of data, and normality and rough equivalence of variances are not an issue.

My question is this:  Is it appropriate or necessary to incorporate the Tukey's Honest post hoc correction to this analysis?  My preference would be to go only up to interactions of two factors; but I strongly suspect I am going to be asked to go all the way and examine even the threes and the four.

(I mean this in the following senses:  Do large factor full factorial analyses typically use HSD corrections?  And are the number of comparisons in this size design large enough to warrant it?)